# Where should I allow uploads and downloads to be saved to?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, download

I'm concerned about security.  I need to allow a specific group of users to upload documents and for all other users to download them.

Where or what folder is the best place to allow this to happen?  I read that outside the root of the site is best but then I've read conflicting posts.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to look at [Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or ask it if there isn't a helpful answer.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends what you need to be able to do with them once they are uploaded.

Outside the web root is definitely best but if you then need to be able to show those files on webpages, you will need to write a handler or just save them inside the webroot.

Ideally you should never allow untrusted users to upload any file to a server and should certainly never allow untrusted users to upload files into a webroot as they could then use your server to spread malware or upload files that can be executed on the server and take control of your server or site.

You should always ensure that the minimum number of file types possible are allowed for upload so if a user is uploading an image, make sure they can only upload images

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  The group that will be uploading will be trusted (it's their site).  I will need to display a list of the documents on other pages though so that the other users can view and download them.  
I'll be using a blacklist of sorts to make sure that only pdfs etc can be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I generally save files to a folder outside the web root (note, not just outside my site root, but outside of the actual web root directory).  You only asked for advice on where best to store the files, but presumably you are taking other steps to make the uploaded files secure (like, changing the name of the file, changing the permissions on the file, etc).  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I wasn't intending on changing the names of these particular files.  What is the benefit of that?  If it's called "Training Handout 1.pdf" I was then hoping to be able to pull that from the database and display it on another page as a link for soemone to download.  And permissions..would you mind explaining please?

Comment: @user2608855 Think about it this way. You have a folder uploads, you store everything there. User A uploads a file called "abc.pdf", the user B uploads another file called "abc.pdf". They are not the same, so what will you do now ? I've see the following solution: when someone uploads a file, you rename the file to a unique filename (for example hashing+timestamp?) and store it in the folder uploads. You store the original filename along with the unique filename in the database so that you can always retrieve them. You can also add other info about the file if you want.

Comment: Well, you don't want someone to upload an executable file (a file that executable permissions) that they can find on your web server (because they know the name of it) and run.  So, I would check the mime-type of the uploaded file to make sure that it's a type of file you're willing to accept (like a PDF or RTF file, for example), then, I'd change the name of it, so you that you know its name, but the uploader doesn't.  Then, using chmod, I'd change the permissions of the file to 0644 http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @HamZa I see, sorry, I was thinking a bit narrowmindedly in that the uploaders wouldn't use the same filename but I guess I can concatenate it with the date.  That would keep original filename integrity and make it unique(including timestamp as you suggested)

Comment: @user2608855 not enough, otherwise you would hope that 2 users don't upload the same filename at the same time :p

Comment: @HamZa - +a sha(microtime)? :)